# Extract Word document menu listings, sublistings and content of each listing to an Excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

im pretty new to VBA and am trying to write a script that takes my word document, and goes through a list, and extracts the titles and content into a excel sheet.

This is what i have so far:

```
Sub ExtractListItems()
    Dim WordApp As Object
    Dim WordDoc As Object
    Dim ExcelApp As Object
    Dim ExcelWorkbook As Object
    Dim ExcelWorksheet As Object
    Dim ListItem As Object
    Dim ListTitle As String
    Dim ListContent As String
    Dim RowCounter As Long
    
    ' Open the Word document
    Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open("C:\Path\To\Word\Document.docx")
    WordApp.Visible = True
    
    ' Create a new Excel workbook and worksheet
    Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set ExcelWorkbook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Add
    Set ExcelWorksheet = ExcelWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    
    ' Loop through each list item and extract the number and title and content
    For Each ListItem In WordDoc.Range.ListFormat.ListString
        ListTitle = ListItem.Range.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text
        ListContent = ListItem.Range.Paragraphs(2).Range.Text
        
        ' Write the data to the Excel worksheet
        RowCounter = RowCounter + 1
        ExcelWorksheet.Cells(RowCounter, 1).Value = ListTitle
        ExcelWorksheet.Cells(RowCounter, 2).Value = ListContent
    Next
    
    ' Save the Excel workbook and close the Word document and Excel application
    ExcelWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Path\To\Excel\Workbook.xlsx"
    ExcelWorkbook.Close
    WordDoc.Close
    ExcelApp.Quit
    WordApp.Quit
End Sub
```

However, it does not work... for some reason my excel freezes... the code compiles but excel just doesnt react anymore..... Can someone help please?

Comment: Are you confusing Headers and Headings? A Header is the area at the top of the page above the top margin. If your code worked it would write the content of the header to Excel multiple times - first the complete content, then each paragraph of that content, then each sentence of each paragraph. You also have 4 undeclared variables, `sec`, `hd`, `subhd`, and `cont`, which have the default datatype of Variant.

Comment: I think you are right here.... - i changed the code above- but am still facing problems :(

Comment: Which application are you running the code from?

Comment: i am running it in excel VBA